# Asp.net Iframe RenderControl

Tags: c#, excel, iframe, asp.net-2.0

trying to render the contents of an IFrame in an Asp.Net Application. 
This is what I currently have.

```
private void ExportToExcel(Control control)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=IT Status "+ReportType.Text+".xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    this.EnableViewState = false;

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    control.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

And my IFrame looks like this

```
<iframe id="ReportBody" runat="server" src="ITTasksByComponent.aspx" scrolling="auto" visible="true" width="1000" height="1000" />
```

When the method runs I get an excel doc with
`<iframe id="ReportBody" src="ITTaskByAssignment" ></iframe>`

I'm suspecting this is something that I'm going to have to run client side in another page using ajax to get working properly but if there is another .NET Serverside solution feel free...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you were expecting the `src` attribute to be evaluated server-side.  To do that you need to use WebClient and get it yourself.  Something like this might work for you.

```
byte[] data = new WebClient.DownloadData(ResolveUrl("~/ITTasksByComponent.aspx");     
Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: I ended up doing pulling from another page using ajax but, if it came down to pulling data at the byte level I probably would have passed on it. Thanks though, for comming up with a viable solution that could have been used had I been unable to change the IFrame to a div (Vis-à-vis explaination to management how much easier it is to do so.)